# How can I convert a JSON text Array to a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

I have the following text object:

```
[{message="Hello World"}]
```

How can I convert this to a JavaScript Array?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the `=` with a `:` and then use JSON.parse. Then you'd need to wrap the message with `"`'s.

```
// error = not :
JSON.parse('[{message="Hello World"}]')

// errors = message not "message"
JSON.parse('[{message="Hello World"}]'.replace('=',':'))
```

Try this:

```
var message = '[{message="Hello World"}]'
message = message.replace('message', '"message"').replace('=',':')
JSON.parse(message)
```

You can use `eval` to do the same:

```
// still gotta replace the '='
eval('[{message="Hello World"}]'.replace("=",":"))
```

But `eval` has other problems:

```
eval('window.alert("eval is evil")')
```

So be careful. Make sure you know what you're eval'ing.

Answer (score 2):

That's [JSON](http://json.org). If you're using jquery, then

```
var arr = jQuery.parseJSON('[{message="Hello World"}]');
alert(arr[0].message);
```

A far less 'safe' method is

```
var arr = eval('[{message="Hello World"}]');
```

after which arr will be the same as the jquery version.

However, it should probably be `[{message:"Hello World"}]` to be proper valid json.

Comment: yes, i just came back to edit the question to state that's it JSON, not HTML. Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not valid JSON, you could replace all `=` with `:`, add quotes to keys, and then convert it using `JSON.parse`:

```
//text = '[{message="Hello World"}]'
text = text.replace(/(\w+)\s*=/g, "\"$1\":");
var array = JSON.parse(text);
```

If `JSON.parse` is not supported, you could use `eval`:

```
//text = '[{message="Hello World"}]'
text = text.replace(/(\w+)\s*=/g, "\"$1\":");
var array = eval("("+text+")");
```

Although that is not recommended.